# How to find the second maximum among an array of string where size of particular element can be 1024?

Tags: c++, string, stl

The array contains `{"-214748364809","-214748364802"}` should "-214748364802".

I tried converting the array elements in integer for any number less than 2147483648. But I cannot convert it to integer if it contains number more than this. Is there any way to compare these numbers?

Comment: The numbers shown would fit comfortably into a 64-bit integer. See `long long`, [`strtoll`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol). What do you mean by "size can be 1024"? 1024 of what units?

Comment: Size means the number of digits (My bad).

Comment: Well, if all you need is to compare them (and not perform any other math), then you can do that directly on strings, without converting to integers. 1. A string without leading dash is greater than one with. 2. After stripping the dash and any leading zeros, the longer string is greater than the shorter string (in absolute value; with negatives, larger absolute value corresponds to smaller number). 3. Strings with the same number of digits can be compared lexicographically.

Comment: This could work when I have only two strings but if array of strings is given and in that also I need to get second max element, then how to do it?

Comment: How would you do it with an array of `int`? Same way here; all you need is the ability to compare two elements to each other.

Comment: ... i.e. write an appropriate less functor (as described by @IgorTandetnik), and then you can compare two strings with it, or use it for `std::sort`, or as custom predicate for `std::set`.

Comment: [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)

Comment: Fun question: Which is better? `nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin() + 1, v.end())` or `partial_sort(v.begin(), v.begin() + 1, v.end())`.  Obviously, this is specific to the fact that we're looking for the second-highest element.

Comment: @MarshallClow looking only at complexities `nth` is linear while `partial` is linear x log2. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: `nth_element` is linear (on what criteria? it doesn't say).  `partial_sort` is `n log n` comparisons.

Comment: After testing on some random data, I can report that `partial_sort` does fewer comparisons and fewer swaps than `nth_element` when attempting to find the second-smallest (or largest) value in a sequence.

Comment: [Check the longer answer in this video!](https://youtu.be/9Tx97HeGnUQ?t=191)

Answer (score -2):

Got the same problem.

```
public static String secondMax(String[] ar) {
    if (ar == null || ar.length == 0 || ar.length == 1)
        return "-1";
    try {
        String largest = ar[0];
        String secLargest = null;
        for (int i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
            String item = ar[i];
            if(compareTo(item, largest) == 0)
                continue;
            if (compareTo(item, largest)  > 0) {
                secLargest = largest;
                largest = item;
            } else if (secLargest == null || compareTo(item, secLargest)  > 0) {
                secLargest = item;
            }
        }
        return Objects.requireNonNullElse(secLargest, "-1");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new InternalError(e);
    }

}
static int compareTo(String ist, String sec)
{
    if(ist.contains("-") && !sec.contains("-"))
        return -1;
    if(!ist.contains("-") && sec.contains("-"))
        return 1;
    if(ist.contains("-") && sec.contains("-"))
    {
        String temp = ist;
        ist = sec;
        sec = temp;
    }
    if (ist.length() > sec.length())
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(ist.length() < sec.length())
    {
        return -1;
    }else {
        return ist.compareTo(sec);
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) It is not clear if you are proposing this as a solution or just stating that you have the same problem. (2) This question is tagged with the C++ language and you code doesn't look like C++.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).